# Hibernate query help

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a Product Class which has one-to-many relationship with ProductInventory Class. For a particular product id, I have around 300 inventory.

If I want to fetch a product based on its id and inventory withing a specified date range, how do i execute a query?

I can go with either hql or criteria..But I'm not sure how to implement it as i'm a beginner in hibernate. Please help.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge of SQL? And did you even try to read through the hibernate hql documentation before posting this question?

Comment: I did...Infact I have a hql join query running fine. But how do I process the output of the query is where i got struck up.

Answer (score 1):

HQL Example,

```
String hql = "FROM Product p WHERE p.id = :id AND p.inventory.date BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2";

Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("id", id);
query.setParameter("date1", date1);
query.setParameter("date2", date2);     

List<Product> products = query.list();
for(Product product : products) {
    System.out.println(product.getId() + "...");
    List<ProductInventory> inventories = product.getProductInventory();
    for(ProductInventory inventory : inventories) {
        System.out.println(inventory.get...);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi rosdi, in the above hql, is inventory a collection?

Comment: Yes of course, it is a one to many relationship right. It could be either a `Set` or a `List`, depending on how you configure it in the mapping/annotation.

Comment: Rosdi, I tried the same in my code. I am getting an exception saying Illegal attempt to dereference a collection...

Comment: Post your mappings/annotations & code so that everybody can comment.

Comment: String hql = "From Product p where p.id = :id and p.inventory.inventoryId.bookDate between :date1 and :date2"; Note that here inventory is a collection. Inventory class has an embedded id out of which one property is bookDate

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to use criteria and for date range you can use

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.between(column_name, minValue,maxValue)).list();
```

For more reference [visit here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html)